# Converting vector to array. How to deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I am converting a vector of doubles to an array of doubles as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923290/6050032):

The difference is, that I want to return the pointer a as a function parameter:

```
void getArray(double* a)
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    a = &v[0];
}
```

So my question is, when does the memory of `a` gets deallocated? Or do I have to call `delete[] a` by myself, which seems strange since I did't allocate the memory with `new`. I have read the comments to the above mentioned answer but it still isn't clear to me.

Comment: `a` will point to garbage, once `v` is out of scope, there is nothing to delete

Comment: As you see there ... is no function call involved.

Comment: @DieterLücking what do you mean? Is not destructor a function?

Comment: @Basilevs I think they mean that no function is explicitly called by the programmer.

Comment: The memory of `a` is deallocated as soon as the function returns, because `a` is a pointer to a vector's element and ´v´ is local to the function.

Comment: Also, next to the UB, from c++11 on, the less hackish version is `v.data()` instead of `&v[0]`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10740171/104774

Comment: "I am converting a vector of doubles to an array of doubles" - Why?

Comment: Anyway, forget about the `getArray` function, just use vectors in your program and use `v.data()` where a vector can't be used (e.g. C interface) making sure that the data used is within the timeline of the vector, which is not the case in your example as already mentioned in the answer of Andrew.

Comment: [Return a pointer to array from a function in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30448688)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I need to convert the vector to an array because the function is part of (C interface) DLL that is called by a LabView VI which doesn't know `vectors`.

Comment: @rkgghz: and would passing v.data() be a reasonable solution then?  After all, that's what is it there for.

Comment: @ stefaanv : I don't think so. Instead I will copy each element to a `new` array and pass that pointer. Then the caller has to delte it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The memory pointed to by `a` gets deallocated when the vector `v` is destructed. In this case, that's at the end of the function `getArray`.

Comment: @Basilevs Depends what OP is trying to do. When *do* you want the memory destructed? Who should be managing this?

Comment: @Basilevs A good approach to memory management would be to keep the vector as a vector and have that manage the memory instead of taking upon oneself to manually manage it. It really depends on the end goal. Sample usage for something that shouldn't be done could suggest that that's the right thing to do. A modern C++ programmer should try to avoid raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
void getArray(double* a)
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    a = &v[0];
} // The vector is destroyed here, and the memory
  // is deallocated.
```

In any case, you're not modifying the `a` pointer outside of your function, so you won't get the desired effect.

Instead, return the `vector` and use it directly. Or, in general, use vectors throughout your code. If you need to pass them *in* to a function that expects a pointer to an array, you can pass `&v[0]` there. Such a function usually expects the size too. For this, pass `v.size()`. You can do this safely as long as that function doesn't take ownership, or deallocate the memory.

Note, also, that a vector declared as `std::vector<double> v;` does not have a size, so attempting to access the first element, as in `v[0]` is also undefined behaviour. At the very least, you need to give the vector a size (pass a size to its constructor) to ensure some memory is allocated. You should always make sure the vector has some allocated memory before indexing into it, including when trying to take the address of the first element.

What you probably want to do is:

```
std::vector<double> getArray() {
  std::vector<double> v = /* some sane initialisation */;
  return v;
}

// some time later, assuming a function:
//   void do_something(double* a, size_t n);
// ...

std::vector<double> v = getArray();
if (v.size()) {
  do_something(&v[0], v.size());
} else {
  // fail gracefully
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This implementation would invoke undefined behavior because `v` is local:

```
void getArray(double* a)
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    a = &v[0]; // would be a UB for returning the pointer to internals of a local variable.
}
```

However, the caller will never see any effect of this, because modifications to `a` stay local to `getArray` function.

If you want to make an array out of a vector, allocate a new array, use `std::copy` to copy the content into it, and return the array to the caller. Make sure the callers call `delete[]` on the result once they are done with the copyL

```
double *getArray(const vector<double>& v) {
    double *res = new double[v.size()];
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), res);
    return res;
}
```

The caller should use it as follows:

```
vector<double> data;
data.push_back(...);
... // populate the vector
double *tmp = getArray(data);
... // Use the array
delete[] tmp; // Avoid memory leaks
```

Comment: i dont think there is ub, because as you said, any modifications to a are local to the function.

Comment: @tobi there is UB when accessing `v[0]` of a vector that has not been constructed with a size.

Comment: @Andrew ah right, and I thought he was referring to dereferencing the invalid pointer (actually "...because `v` is local" is misleadling)

Comment: Consider adding a method documentation in form of a comment. IMHO, this is a good practice when returning raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> when does the memory of a gets deallocated?

The `a` pointer itself is a local variable, so it is deallocated at the end of its scope.

`a` points to the memory allocated by the vector `v`. The pointed memory is deallocated in the destructor of `v` (The memory may also be deallocated if objects are added to or removed from the vector). And because `v` is a local variable, it is destroyed at the end of scope.

> Or do I have to call delete[] a by myself,

No, because the memory is owned by the vector object, but also because

> which seems strange since I did't allocate the memory with new.

Exactly. You didn't call `new[]`, so you don't call `delete[]`.

---

Note that `v[0]` has undefined behaviour because the vector is empty.